# Yellow spots on cactus, brown spines

Tags: identification, diagnosis, cactus

I have a cactus in which some yellow spots are appearing, some are starting to turn brown even.

Then the spines seem to be dark brown on the top and white on the sides. Not sure if that's normal.

I notice the yellow spots are more noticeable in the front side of the cactus (facing the sun). I wonder if that means there's too much sun, or maybe not related. The cactus is placed outside of a window in Madrid (Spain) where it gets direct sunlight in the morning (facing East).

The pot has wholes below, but the recipient in which it is does not (it's a robot). BUT the pot doesn't get to the bottom, so, there's water in the recipient, but the pot is not touching that water. Is that a problem? I'd expect it isn't since water is not in contact with the pot. The soil is actually quite dry... maybe too much?

Also, I don't know what species it is, I think it's a [Echinocactus platyacanthus](https://plantsam.com/echinocactus-platyacanthus/) but may very well be wrong.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Front:
[image: Front of cactus]

Back:
[image]